# How can I default the date of a Maui .NET DatePicker to today's date?

Tags: .net, datepicker, maui

Whenever I load the Event page, it always defaults the date to some random date in 1924. How can I default the date to today's date, so that a User doesn't have to scroll through all dates between then and now to select a date in the future?

- I tried setting the EventDate after InitializeComponent
- I tried setting the default date in the XAML but found there was no way to update the binding when the default date was set there
- I tried defaulting it by auto assigning it to the property itself

Comment: I will do, but it requires 48 hours from Original Question posting :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default values of any control by updating the bound Property in the constructor of the ContentPage.

When updating the Property, you need to make sure it is updated before InitializeComponent() is called in the class constructor, otherwise the value will be reset to the default value once the form is loaded.

e.g. Event ContentPage.cs

```
public partial class EventPage : ContentPage
{
    public EventPage() // All pages need a default, empty constructor for the XAML previewer
    {
        EventDate = DateTime.Now; // Any default page values must be set before InitializeComponent() is called, otherwise the values get overridden
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; } // The properties that the page binds to need to have the same name as the properties in the model
}
```

and Event ContentPage.xaml

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <DatePicker 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Date="{Binding EventDate}" 
        Format="D"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```